# Exchange Web Services on Windows 10 IoT Core (UAP)

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, windows-10-iot-core

I'm developing an application in C# that should run on a Raspberry Pi 2 running Windows 10 IoT Core. I want to use Exchange Web Services to access our Exchange server. My problem is that I can't get EWS to work together with the universal windows application that's supposed to run on the Raspberry. When I try to add the package in NuGet I get the following error message:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices 2.2.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
```

If I download the DLL's manually from Microsoft and add them in Visual Studio I can compile and deploy the code but as soon as the application starts and tries to run the first line:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
```

I get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in Microsoft.Exchange.
WebServices.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core,
Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of 
its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match 
the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I don't get why it can't load System.Core. I even tried to add System.Core as a reference but VS obviously won't let me since it's there from the beginning.

Does anyone have any tips at all on how to get EWS to work with my application?

Regards

Comment: Looks like it's just not compatible. And if you don't have the source code for EWS, you can't really recompile it. Perhaps instead of connecting to Exchange via EWS, you write a proxy (perhaps using ASP.NET Web API) that you can talk to over HTTP, and then that program will talk to Exchange for you?

Comment: The source for the EWS Managed API is available on GitHub because of the dependences used I don't believe it will work in UAP see https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/issues/5 for a discussion. You can use EWS just using httpclient and submitting the SOAP request and process the responses or use WSDL to generate proxy objects.